# How can I increment my progress bar by a button click on tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, button, progress-bar

I copied the example from codemy.com. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Grbx15jRjQA

When I run the program I get the bar and the button. But once I click the button to increment the progress bar, I get this error.

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Can someone help me fix this error please?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Test bar")
root.geometry("600x400")


def step():
    my_progress["value"] += 20


my_progress = ttk.Progressbar(
    root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='determinate').pack(pady=20)


my_button = Button(root, text="Progress", command=step).pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with ttk.progressbar, so my research was not exhaustive but I couldn't find the way you are trying to access the value.
I think that the best way to do it would be to create an IntVar() to store the progress bar's progress, and assign it to the progress bar, as such:

```py
progress = IntVar()

def step():
    progress.set(progress.get() + 20)

my_progress = ttk.Progressbar(
    root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='determinate', variable=progress).pack(pady=20)
```

The progress will update automatically when you change the IntVar's value through the set method, I tested it myself and it worked.

Comment: Hey @Aliup! Glad it helped you. For future reference and other people who need help, I think it'd be great if you'd mark this problem as solved by clicking the checkmark near the points of my answer, that way you'd be marking it as correct and everyone would be able to see that it solves the problem.

Comment: I feel like something is missing because when I run my program, the progress bar goes from empty to full when the functions completed.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have assigned the result of `pack()` (which is `None`) to `my_progress` in the following line:

```
my_progress = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='determinate').pack(pady=20)
```

You need to split it into two lines:

```
my_progress = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='determinate')
my_progress.pack(pady=20)
```